# Ethernet Connection randomly disconnects after transmit queue 0 timed out

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

**Description of problem:**

Ethernet connection gets disconnected at random apparently without any reason. I have tried the following command to restart my ethernet connection,

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

though it never solved the issue. Every time I have to restart my system to get the connection back.

**Details of my Ethernet card:**

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:30a1]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k<br>
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:392e]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

**My system:** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit on Lenovo ideapad z560.

> **OBSERVATION:** It happens more frequently when I make calls in skype or hangout. It seems that heavy usage of Ethernet is causing the disconnection.

**Debug steps tried so far:**

I found a post [Wired Network is not stable in ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287779/wired-network-is-not-stable-in-ubuntu-13-04-64-bit) have something similar problem description as mine but not exactly. Following the solution given in that post, I installed and tried to use an older kernel `linux-image-3.5.0-27-generic`. But the same problem persisted there.

At the same time I am not sure if it is a hardware related issue as this never happened with Windows 7 which I was using before. I did a lot of googling but could not find a solution except a few about older versions and bug report.

As a hint to look into `dmesg` [ thanks to @noleti ], I found the following:

```
$ dmesg -T | grep eth0
[Sat May  2 19:52:37 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: RTL8102e at 0xffffc90000348000, 88:ae:1d:3a:ec:ff, XID 04e00000 IRQ 41
[Sat May  2 19:52:45 2015] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[Sat May  2 19:52:51 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link down
[Sat May  2 19:52:51 2015] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[Sat May  2 19:52:51 2015] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[Sat May  2 19:52:56 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link up
[Sat May  2 19:52:56 2015] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[Sat May  2 20:09:01 2015] NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
[Sat May  2 20:09:01 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link up
[Sat May  2 20:09:13 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link up
[Sat May  2 20:09:19 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link up
[Sat May  2 20:09:31 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link up
[Sat May  2 20:10:13 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link up
[Sat May  2 20:10:55 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link up
[Sat May  2 20:12:07 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link up
[Sat May  2 20:13:49 2015] r8169 0000:07:00.0: eth0: link up
```

After the event as shown in `dmesg` output my connection is lost.

```
NETDEV WATCHDOG: eth0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
```

Comment: it's unclear to me if you're using ethernet or wifi

Comment: @MrVaykadji ethernet using LAN cable

Comment: @MrVaykadji I tried the kernel given here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/287779/wired-network-is-not-stable-in-ubuntu-13-04-64-bit.....But did not solve the problem. Its unstable as before.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the drivers?

Comment: @Ron I reinstalled ubuntu once......but nothing changed

Comment: I have the same *ethernet* controller; except it's *rev 05*. It's working fine. You need to find out if it's a hardware problem, driver problem or higher tcp/ip stack problem. You can first try some other OS like [freebsd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159264/how-to-create-a-freebsd-10-bootable-usb) to test the hardware.

Comment: @solsTiCe i was using windows few months before ..... but this never happened.

Comment: After such a disconnect, will `dmesg` yield any related error? Do you have LEDs indicating physical connection, and what do they say after a disconnect?

Comment: @sssss Well if you don't want make some test.... You could try the [realtek driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470609/rtl8101e-rtl8102e-not-working-with-ubuntu-14-04-hp-g61?rq=1)

Comment: @noleti it gives lot of things. how do i know there is an error?

Comment: @solsTiCe I have no idea  what **higher tcp/ip stack problem** is. I will try  the realtek driver soon.

Comment: @solsTiCe @noleti :Since all efforts failed. I have removed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and installed Ubuntu 12.04.         
Kernel version:`3.2.0-83-generic`
Internet connection is very stable.  It never got disconnected after I switched to 12.04. But it is still not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I tried to replace `r8169` with `r8168` which happens to be a bug for many users having `Realtek Ethernet Controller`, but never solved the problem, even now almost an year after posting this. I face the same problem even with the latest kernel update `4.2.0-30-generic`.

**Solution:**

Replace the current kernel with a stable older kernel version, in my case I installed kernel version `3.2.0-83-generic` manually in `14.04 LTS`. Now the Ethernet connection is stable and the problem is solved.

Download the following `.deb` packages from [1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/linux-headers-3.2.0-83/3.2.0-83.120), [2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/linux-headers-3.2.0-83-generic/download), [3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/i386/linux-image-3.2.0-83-generic/download), [4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/uk/precise-updates/i386/linux-image-extra-3.2.0-83-virtual/download) and install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.2.0-83_3.2.0-83.120_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.2.0-83-generic_3.2.0-83.120_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.2.0-83-generic_3.2.0-83.120_i386.deb
```

You can change the boot order by editing `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` in `/etc/default/grub` as given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader). Then

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

I think you can try to install other latest `v3.2` kernels which too may be stable, Ex: `3.2.0-98-generic`

**Note:** I have tested it for both 32bit and 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Thanks for documenting your journey through all of this. I have a Cenovo Mini PC 2 which contains a Realtek r8152 ethernet adapter and had very very similar problems to yours when running Ubuntu 16.04—dropping the network connection when high load occurred. I tried everything under the sun until I read your issue here and tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 (with kernel 3.13). It's worked perfectly ever since. As you say though... hardly a solution.

Comment: @jeff-h you said 3.13 works fine with 12.04. try installing `14.04` or `16.04` and manually replace the kernel with `3.13`.

Comment: Thanks for your followup. Unfortunately I'm not deep enough into Ubuntu to know how or why to do that, although it sounds interesting. Luckily all I need to do is run Docker, nothing else. I realise there are numerous lighter distros for that but I had no luck with any of them on this Cherry Trail PC (but that's a side issue.)

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try to limit the speed of the ethernet adapter ? Try:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex half
```

Or if this does not help, try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37727/solving-ethernet-watchdog-timer-deadlocks

Comment: i tried this but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

as from `dmesg -T | grep eth0` output, you are using `r8169` driver which [has been unstable for few network cards](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/141343)
try manually [downgrading](https://superuser.com/questions/703994/how-to-replace-the-driver-of-realtek-8111-8169-nic-to-8111-8168) driver to `r8168`

hope this helps

Comment: nope......network is still the same.....unstable as before