# Can I use a 12.04 kernel (v3.2) with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS instead of v3.13/4.2?

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, kernel

As refer to my earlier problems with 14.04, [Ethernet Connection randomly disconnects after transmit queue 0 timed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615423/ethernet-connection-randomly-disconnects-after-transmit-queue-0-timed-out)

I was having trouble using Ethernet in 14.04, and this problem still persists with any latest kernel versions (current kernel: `4.2.0.30-generic`). The solution I found to the this problem was to shift to `12.04` with kernel `3.2.0-83-generic` and then the Ethernet connection became stable.

Now after upgrading to `15.10` I switched back to `12.04` with kernel `3.11.0-15-generic`, but now I am facing the same Ethernet problem as i referred, in `14.04`. But now I am facing another problem referred to [Unity launcher reset after each reboot and unable to change wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/740225/unity-launcher-reset-after-each-reboot-and-unable-to-change-wallpaper), which I am unable to find a solution in any forums.

**Note:**

1. The above issues happen in both 32bit and 64bit.
2. I have tried to replace `r8169` with `r8168` but it never solved the problem. So from my experience with stable internet in certain kernel versions in `12.04` and from [Wired Network is not stable in ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287779/wired-network-is-not-stable-in-ubuntu-13-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B04-64-bit), which seems to be a similar problem, changing the kernel seems to be the best option i have.

So considering my above problems, is it somehow possible to use kernel v3.2 in ubuntu 14.04 ?

How do i install this old kernel, it'd be nice if someone give me a step by step procedure to do it manually from terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Changing from `r8169` to `r8168` may not work in all cases, considering my case and from some other similar posts on older ubuntu versions, it seems like changing the kernel to an old stable version is the best option one has unless it is not fixed in the latest updates.

Finally I installed an older kernel version `3.2.0-83-generic` in `14.04 LTS` (32bit) manually. It solved my ethernet problem and it seems to be stable enough.

Download the following `.deb` packages from [1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/linux-headers-3.2.0-83/3.2.0-83.120), [2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/linux-headers-3.2.0-83-generic/download), [3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/i386/linux-image-3.2.0-83-generic/download), [4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/uk/precise-updates/i386/linux-image-extra-3.2.0-83-virtual/download) and install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.2.0-83_3.2.0-83.120_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.2.0-83-generic_3.2.0-83.120_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-3.2.0-83-generic_3.2.0-83.120_i386.deb
```

Change the boot order by editing `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` in `/etc/default/grub` as given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader). Then:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```