# 14.04 LTS intermittent wifi connection problem

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have just bought an ASUS E402M and have installed Ubuntu 14.04.

I installed Ubuntu, replacing Windows which was originally installed.

I have been having an intermittent problem connecting to my router/the internet.

I have several devices (Mac/Android Tablet/Kindle/iPhone/Windows laptop) that have no connection problems at all.

Symptom of my problem:  after varying lengths of time varying from 30 minutes to 1 minute, I will lose connection to the internet.  (I think this is especially if I have been browsing.)  Rebooting the E402M will temporarily fix the problem.

Attempting to upgrade to a higher version of Linux rendered the ASUS inoperable.

Is there a solution?

Comment: running lspci -v informs me that the ethernet controller is: Realtek RTL810E/RTL8102E

Comment: That's the Ethernet controller, but can you give us the Wireless one? Instead of just lspci -v, please, run $ sudo lspci -vvnn

Comment: the output is too big to post.  Which section did you want?

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
 Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:1723]
 Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
 Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
 Region 0: I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
 Region 2: Memory at d0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

Comment: Followed this post, but still getting problem http://askubuntu.com/questions/470609/rtl8101e-rtl8102e-not-working-with-ubuntu-14-04-hp-g61

Comment: Search for "Wireless" and copy the information about your wireless card (including the PCIID (the number in brackets)). Also, what kernel version are you using? (you can find out by running $ uname -a)

Comment: Version 3.19.0-25-generic

Comment: Was the section I posted what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issues with the driver of this Wireless card.

The main Ubuntu issue to follow for updates and workarounds is [bug 1320070](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1320070]).

On the [Kernel bugzilla issue](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83641) you can see that this will probably be fixed in kernel 4.0.

In the mean time, you can follow [this workaround](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83641#c1), combined with [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1320070/comments/39). The workarounds are not perfect, but they seem to be helping making the wireless connection more stable for a lot of people.

Comment: Followed the above two workarounds.  So far there has been much improvement.  Many thanks Ara.