# ubuntu 16.04 is not detecting ethernet

Tags: internet

I have upgraded my Ubuntu recently to 16.04. Previously, in 14.04 Ethernet was going fine but since last 2days my laptop is not detecting the Ethernet connection even though the connection is working in windows.
I tried to restart the network manager which failed. kingly suggest some idea.

Comment: kindly attach to your question a screenshot of > lspci -vnn | grep Network so we can check what network controller you are using

Comment: @Yien on my system it returns the wifi adapter **NOT** ethernet: `$  lspci -vnn | grep Network` returns `3c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
 Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]` On the other hand: `$ lspci -vnn | grep Ethernet` gives the desired result: `3b:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0a1] (rev 10)`

Comment: well then i do believe you need to install the drivers first looking on to your ethernet controller see this link:https://askubuntu.com/questions/670347/is-there-any-way-to-install-atheros-e2400-drivers try it and see if your ethernet connection is now working

Comment: @Yien Sorry if I misled you. Both my Wifi and my Ethernet work perfectly. I was only pointing out your comment reveals WiFi properties when it is Ethernet properties the OP needs to tell us. Perhaps `lspci` without any grepping is the best output to copy and paste into his question?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, thank you for pointing that i overlooked it  and @Jagannath you can edit then copy and paste with your `lspci -vnn | grep Ethernet` in your question above so others can see it clearly

Comment: @Yien it returns "lspci -vnn | grep Ethernet
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
 Subsystem: Dell RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [1028:0654]"

Comment: @Jagannath kindly try the solution in this link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470609/rtl8101e-rtl8102e-not-working-with-ubuntu-14-04-hp-g61, i do believe you need to install the drivers first before your ethernet to work properly